# Is there a python only version of mediapipe?

Tags: python-module, pose-estimation, mediapipe

I am currently working with a JeVois camera. Code I have previously written for pose estimation with high performance and only using a cpu uses Mediapipe. However, JeVois is not very friendly with added libraries like mediapipe as it is mostly c++ libraries. Does anyone know if there is a version of mediapipe that the dependencies are purely in python? Or does anyone know a workaround solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a python only version of mediapipe. It is mentioned in the documentation.

You can install it using

```
pip install mediapipe
```

(https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/)